# Особенности перехода с Smarty 2 на Smarty 3 (mysmarty.class.php)

Tags: php, классы, архитектура, smarty

Всем привет, меняю "движок" т.е. Smarty 2 на Smarty 3, в настройках скрипта(config.php) на PHP с использованием Smarty 2 есть:

```
require_once($config['basedir'].'/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/mysmarty.class.php');
...
STemplate::assign ...
STemplate::setCompileDir ...
STemplate::setTplDir ...
```

В index.php(главный в корне домена) есть:

```
STemplate::display('header.tpl');
STemplate::display('index.tpl');
STemplate::display('footer.tpl');
```

Smarty.class.php стандартный(все с комментариями), а в специальном файле(mysmarty.class.php) есть такое:

```
<?php

class STemplate {

   function STemplate() {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            $Smarty = new Smarty;
        }
    }

    function create() {
        global $Smarty;
        $Smarty = new Smarty();
        $Smarty->compile_check = true;
        $Smarty->debugging = false;
        $Smarty->template_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../themes";
        $Smarty->compile_dir  = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../temporary";

        return true;
    }

    function setCompileDir($dir_name) {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create();
        }
        $Smarty->compile_dir = $dir_name;
    }

    function setType($type) {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create();
        }
        $Smarty->type = $type;
    }

    function assign($var, $value) {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create();
        }
        $Smarty->assign($var, $value);
    }

    function setTplDir($dir_name = null) {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create();
        }
        if (!$dir_name) {
            $Smarty->template_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../themes/default";
        } else {
            $Smarty->template_dir = $dir_name;
        }
    }

    function setModule($module) {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create();
        }
        $Smarty->theme = $module;
        $Smarty->type  = "module";
    }

    function setTheme($theme) {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create();
        }
        $Smarty->template_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../themes/" . $theme;
        $Smarty->compile_dir  = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../temporary/" . $theme;
        $Smarty->theme        = $theme;
        $Smarty->type         = "theme";
    }

    function getTplDir() {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create();
        }
        return $Smarty->template_dir;
    }

    function display($filename) {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create();
        }
        $Smarty->display($filename);
    }

    function fetch($filename) {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create();
        }
        return $Smarty->fetch($filename);
    }

    function getVars() {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create();
        }
        return $Smarty->get_template_vars();
    }
}
?>
```

Вызов функций в файлах идет с STemplate:: ...

Вопрос, надо ли что-то менять в mysmarty.class.php при переходе с Smarty 2 на Smarty 3 (кроме файлов от разработчика)? P.S. foreach в файле шаблона проекта работает

Comment: Пока под вопросом использование Smarty, очень много ньюансов

Comment: честно сказать, этот ваш класс `STemplate` в принципе бесполезная шляпа какая-то. В принципе это подобие реализации синглтона на глобальной переменной с основными функциями смарти.

Comment: по сабжу, менять ничего вроде не надо. с виду.